# How to create make file for only object and header file?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm performing blackbox testing using a `set.h` interface where I have no access to `set.c`, I've been provided with the object file `set.o` and I'm required to write a bunch of tests in a `main.c` file for the set. How do I create a makefile that would include `set.o`, `set.h` and `main.c`?

**I already have the set.o file so I don't have to regenerate it using set.c

I'm confused because I only know how to do this using the complete files.

Here's my template

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

PROG = example
HDRS = set.h
SRCS = main.c 

OBJDIR = object
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/set.o

# compiling rules

$(PROG): $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

$(OBJDIR)/set.o: set.h $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c set.h -o $(OBJDIR)/set.o

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: main.c $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o $(OBJDIR)/main.o

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Check your compilers options for link-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the set.o file there is no need to create a rule for it, just use it. Also note I got rid of the mkdir because if you already have a `set.o`, it should already be in objects/ right?

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

PROG = example
HDRS = set.h
SRCS = main.c 

OBJDIR = object
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o

# compiling rules

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/set.o -o $(PROG)

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: main.c $(HDRS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o $(OBJDIR)/main.o

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: I keep getting this error, `Makefile:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: If you are copying and pasting make sure there are tabs and not spaces. Just realized you were using clang. Try the edited answer.

Comment: So I've implemented that. Now, when I use make it says `clang -g -Wall -c main.c -o object/main.o` and then goes on to say error:use of identifier set. The set declaration is in set.h

Comment: do you have `#include "set.h" ` in main.c?

Comment: It works when I change $(OBJDIR)/set.o to set.o, why?

Comment: Good question. Not sure. Is set.o in the same directory as main.c?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148703/discussion-between-ekeith-and-atomsmasher).